# how to open fancybox gallery with button helpers "manually"

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I do not want to show any thumbnails on the page.  I just want a text link that opens up a sequence of images that they can play in a slideshow.  I'm using jquery and fancybox 2.  I pasted this together form some examples I found, but instead of showing me the images it shows me the text of the img src.

```
html:
<a href="javascript:;" class="img_seq">Gallery</a>

js:       


$('.img_seq').click(function() {
    $.fancybox(['http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4044/4286199901_33844563eb.jpg',
         'http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2687/4220681515_cc4f42d6b9.jpg'],
        {   

    helpers: { 
        buttons : {}
    }

        });
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easy:

```
$(".img_seq").click(function() {
        $.fancybox([
            'http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4044/4286199901_33844563eb.jpg',
            'http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2687/4220681515_cc4f42d6b9.jpg',
            {
                'href'  : 'http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4005/4213562882_851e92f326.jpg',
                'title' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit'
            }
        ], {
            'padding'           : 0,
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'type'              : 'image',
            'changeFade'        : 0
        });
    });
```

source: [Fancybox.net](http://fancybox.net/)

Comment: that's what i started out with too, but when i added the "buttons" helpers, the images turned into text.

Comment: oh nm, i guess i do need the other options like 'type' : 'image', but how do i get rid of the downward scrolling animation?

Comment: the answer is: prevEffect : 'none',
  nextEffect : 'none',